Creation of products and equalizers implies that of general limits?
Consider a functor $F\colon\mathscr{C\to D}$.

$F$ is said to create limits of a diagram $D\colon\mathscr{I\to C}$ if (i) $F$ reflects limits of $D$, and (ii) if $FD$ has a limit cone, then some isomorphic copy of it lifts to a cone over $D$.

Now, the construction of arbitrary limits from products and equalizers is well-known, and this prompts me to ask whether the creation of products and equalizers implies that of limits.
In other words, is the following statement true?

If $F$ creates, and $\mathscr D$ has, products and equalizers, then $F$ creates arbitrary limits as well.

I think that one also needs that $F$ be conservative for this to be true, but I am not sure.

EDIT
The following lemma (which I have proved) comes in handy:

Lemma. Let $D\colon\mathscr{I\to C}$ be a diagram. Assume the following:

$(P', \{\pi'_i\})$ and $(Q', \{\pi'_\alpha\})$ be products in $\mathscr C$ of $FD_i$'s and $FD(\operatorname{codom}\alpha)$'s for objects $i$'s and morphisms $\alpha$'s of $\mathscr I$.
$(P, \{\pi_i\})$ and $(Q, \{\pi_\alpha\})$ be the products in $\mathscr C$ of $Di$'s and $D(\operatorname{codom}\alpha)$'s, whose $F$-images are also products in $\mathscr D$.
$\mu'\colon(P', \{\pi'_i\})\to (FP, \{F\pi_i\})$ and $\nu'\colon(Q', \{\pi'_\alpha\})\to(FQ, \{F\pi_\alpha\})$ be (the unique existent) isomorphisms.
$f', g'\colon P'\to Q'$ be the morphisms defined by $f'\pi'_\alpha = \pi'_{\operatorname{codom}\alpha}$ and $g'\pi'_\alpha = (FD\alpha) \pi'_{\operatorname{dom}\alpha}$.
$f, g\colon P\to Q$ be similarly defined.

Then the following diagrams commute:

Thus, $(E', e')$ is an equalizer of $f', g'\colon P'\to Q'$ iff $(E', \mu' e')$ is an equalizer of $Ff, Fg\colon FP\to FQ$. Further, if $(E, e)$ is an equalizer of $f$, $g$ whose $F$-image is also an equalizer, then the unique equalizer isomorphism $(E', \mu'e')\to F(E, e)$ also defines an isomorphism of the $D$-limits $(E', \{\pi'_i e'\})\to F(E, \{\pi_i e\})$.

Now, on to the main proof:
Suppose that $F$ creates products and equalizers. We need to show among two things that $F$ reflects limits. (The first is an easy consequence of the lemma.) So, let $(C, \theta)$ be a cone over a diagram $D\colon\mathscr{I\to C}$ such that $F(C, \theta)$ (which is just $(FC, \{F\theta_i\})$) is a limit cone over $FD$. We need to show that $(C, \theta)$ is a limit cone over $D$.
Form the products $(P', \{\pi'_i\})$ and $(Q', \{\pi'_\alpha\})$ of $FDi$'s and $FD(\operatorname{codom}\alpha)$'s, and an equalizer $(E', e')$ of $f', g'$. (This way, $(E', \{\pi'_i e'\})$ will be a limit of $FD$ and would thus be isomorphic to $F(C, \theta)$.)
Since $F$ creates products, we have products $(P, \{\pi_i\})$ and $(Q, \{\pi_\alpha\})$ of $Di$'a and $D(\operatorname{codom}\alpha)$'s whose $F$-images are products of $FDi$'s and $FD(\operatorname{codom}\alpha)$'s respectively. Thus, we have $\mu'$ and $\nu'$ as outlined in the lemma, so that $(E', \mu' e')$ is an equalizer of $Ff, Fg\colon FP\to FQ$.
Since $F$ also creates equalizers, there exists an equalizer $(E, e)$ of $f, g\colon P\to Q$ whose $F$-image is an equalizer of $Ff, Fg\colon FP\to FQ$.
Now, we have $F(C, \theta)\cong(E', \{\pi'_i e'\})\cong F(E, \{\pi_i e\})$ (the last congruence following from the lemma).
I'd be done if I can conclude that $(C, \theta)\cong (E, \{\pi_i e\})$. And to ensure this, I don't see any way other than demanding that $F$ be conservative.

Could you explain a bit where you are getting stuck? At a first glance, it seems to me that if you dig into the construction of limits by products and equalizers, this should go through. I suspect this might have something to do with your notion of "creation of limits" being non-unique. If that is the case I would imagine that the requirement that F be conservative cannot be dropped (though I would be hard-pressed over how to find an example).

Oh, yet another definition. The discussion at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/created+limit is relevant here.

But I agree with Rodrigo here. I wrote down the proof and nothing really happened. Curious where you use that $F$ is conservative?

@MartinBrandenburg Just to comment to the definitions: The definition that I state is what Reihl uses, which match with the n-lab's definition if $FD$ has a limit.

@MartinBrandenburg Can you share the proof that you wrote down?

@RodrigoNicolauAlmeida I have edited to show my though process.

With the help of the tutor of the course, I could figure it out. It turns out that the answer is much simpler.
We just need one (simply proven) result:

Result. Let $(C, \theta)$ be a cone over a diagram $D\colon\mathscr{I\to C}$. Let $(P, \{\pi_i\})$, $(Q, \{\pi_\alpha\})$ be products of $Di$'s and $D(\operatorname{codom}\alpha)$'s (for $i\in\operatorname{Obj}\mathscr I$ and $\alpha\in\operatorname{Mor}\mathscr I$) and $f, g\colon P\to Q$ be defined by $\pi_\alpha f = \pi_{\operatorname{codom}\alpha}$ and $\pi_\alpha g = (D\alpha)\pi_{\operatorname{dom}\alpha}$. Define $e\colon C\to P$ by $\pi_i e = \theta_i$. Then $(C, \theta)$ is a limit of $D$ $\iff$ $(C, e)$ is an equalizer of $f$, $g$.

Now, on to the proof: It's given that $F(C, \theta)$ is a limit of $FD$. Since $F$ creates, and $\mathscr D$ has, products, take products $(P, \{\pi_i\})$, $(Q, \{\pi_\alpha\})$ of $Di$'s and $D(\operatorname{codom}\alpha)$'s whose $F$-images are also products. Define $f$, $g$ as in the result above. Define $e\colon C\to P$ as in the result above. Then "$\Rightarrow$" part of the result (applied to the $F$-images) implies that $(FC, Fe)$ is an equalizer of $Ff, Fg$. Since $D$ reflects equalizers, we get that $(C, e)$ is an equalizer of $f, g$, so that "$\Leftarrow$" part of the result implies that $(C, \theta)$ is a limit of $D$.
